# Could someone tell me in what code this is written

Tags: codeigniter

i've got a message telling:

TFO COBRBK RKP AXOXRC PFB FK BFKBJ MBOPLBKIFZEBK DBPMOXBZE HBKKBK WR IBOKBK. YFQQB JBIABK PFB PFZE CRBO BFKB QBOJFKXYPMOXZEB QBIBCLKFPZE YBF RKP

I was told that its an old code.
If someone  could tell me in which code it is written i'd be very greatfull.

Best Regards. ~Nyu

Comment: Looks like the famous Vinaigrette Cipher. It hasn't been solved yet as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't deal with ciphers. We only deal with computer code. You could try http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ but you need to read the help center before posting.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

It's a monoalphabetic substitution code, like the Caesar Chiffre. Letters are shifted by -3 (or +23): A "D" is ciphered as "A", E->B, F->C and so on.

It reads (in German):

wir freuen uns darauf sie in einem persoenlichen gespraech kennen zu lernen. bitte melden sie sich fuer eine terminabsprache telefonisch bei uns

Which roughly means:

"We are looking forward to meet you in person. Please call back for an appointment."